# How can i apply changes so my feature modules will work

Tags: angular

I have feature users feature module.But the routing dont work.
As you can see in the app.module.ts i am loading first the feature module where it has a 
login path,agter that the app routing module where the wild card is.But is is not working like that.I dont get any routing errors in the console.When i click on the login button which should redirect to that path it makes nothing.But if the the login path is in the app routing module then it works.

Where is my mistake ?

```
// users-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule { }

// user.module.ts

@NgModule ({
    imports: [
        UsersRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent]
})

export class UsersModule {}

// app routing module

const appRoutes: Routes = [
   //{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AnonymousGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        NgDatepickerModule
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}

// app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    //ComcastContractComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
]
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should replace `imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]` with

```
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]
```

in users-routing.module.ts and remove the same in user.module.ts. forChild does not include the router service